# NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps - maps

Tags: jenkins

I have below jenkinsfile script and want to export value configure on the map but I get error: "**NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps**"

```
  stage ('Set env') {
      steps {
          script {
             print "" +
             "---------------------------------------\n" +
             "GIT_AUTHOR         : ${env.GIT_AUTHOR}\n" +
             "---------------------------------------"
          }
      }
  }

  stage ('Deploy to K8s') {
    steps {
        script {
            script {
            def currentUser = "${GIT_AUTHOR}"
            def user = ["${currentUser}" : "nameserverk8s-pit"]
            def userNamespace = "nameserverk8s-${user[${currentUser}]}"
            echo "${userNamespace}"
        }

        }


    }
  }
```

I want that echo return : **nameserverk8s-pit** but it give me error like:

```
NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps
```

I found the solution, maybe there are other more good , but for the moment this is working:

```
            def currentUser = "${GIT_AUTHOR}"
            def user = [users: [currentUser : 'nameserverk8s-pit']]
            def userNamespace = user['users'].currentUser
            echo "${userNamespace}"
```

Comment: You syntax is malformed, just use: `def userNamespace = "nameserverk8s-${user[currentUser]}"` in your original code.

Comment: this will give me the result: "nameserverk8s-null"